# How to parse this json objects on recyclerview?

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-recyclerview

I want to show this json in recyclerview. how can I do it? 
I just want to list "user" and "exchangeName".

My Json;

> {
>   "events": {
>       "101": {
>           "id": "0001",
>           "type": "exchange",
>           "user": "BTUser01",
>           "exchangeName": "BTCTurk",
>           "transactions": {
>                   "send": "249",
>                   "get": "24.1"
>                   },
>           "certificate": [
>                   "BTUser01Certificate"
>                   ]
>           },
>       "102": {
>           "id": "0002",
>           "type": "exchange",
>           "user": "BTUser02",
>           "exchangeName": "Koinim",
>           "transactions": {
>                   "send": "300",
>                   "get": "641"
>                   },
>           "certificate": [
>                   "BTUser02Certificate"
>                   ]
>           },
>       "103": {
>           "id": "0003",
>           "type": "exchange2",
>           "user": "BTUser03",
>           "exchangeName": "Koineks",
>           "transactions": {
>                   "send": "823",
>                   "get": "751"
>                   },
>           "certificate": [
>                   "BTUser03Certificate"
>                   ]
>           },
>       "104": {
>           "id": "0004",
>           "type": "exchange3",
>           "user": "BTUser04",
>           "exchangeName": "Paribu",
>           "transactions": {
>                   "send": "543",
>                   "get": "3.1"
>                   },
>           "certificate": [
>                   "BTUser04Certificate"
>                   ]
>           }
>       }
>   }

MainActivity;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView ev, ev2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ev);
        ev2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ev2);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("MYAPİ_ADRESS_LINK").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        Service service = retrofit.create(Service.class);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getData();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String res = null;
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        try {
                            res = response.body().string();
                            parse(res);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                int a = 0;
            }
        });

    }

    Model parse(String str) {
        Model model = new Model();
        try {
            String source = str.replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "");
            String s = new Gson().toJson(source);
            s = s.replace("\\","");
            s = s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s).getJSONObject("events");
            Iterator<String> iter = object.keys();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                String key = iter.next();
                try {
                    JSONObject value = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(object.get(key)));
                    model.setExternalId(Integer.parseInt(key));
                    model.setUser(value.getString("user"));
                    model.setSend(value.getString("send"));

                    ev.setText(model.user);
                    ev2.setText(model.send);


                    return model;


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // Something went wrong!
                }
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

My Model;

```
public class Model {

    int externalId;
    int id;
    String type;
    String user;
    String exchangeName;
    Transactions transactions;






    List<certificate> certificateList;

    public int getExternalId() {
        return externalId;
    }

    public void setExternalId(int externalId) {
        this.externalId = externalId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getExchangeName() {
        return exchangeName;
    }

    public void setExchangeName(String exchangeName) {
        this.exchangeName = exchangeName;
    }

    public Transactions getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(Transactions transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    public List<certificate> getCertificateList() {
        return certificateList;
    }

    public void setCertificateList(List<certificate> certificateList) {
        this.certificateList = certificateList;
    }

    class Transactions{
        String send;

        String get;

        public String getSend() {
            return send;
        }

        public void setSend(String send) {
            this.send = send;
        }

        public String getGet() {
            return get;
        }

        public void setGet(String get) {
            this.get = get;
        }
    }

    class certificate{
        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you could have found this answer easily in the hundreds of tutorials and guides available.

To achieve this you will need to create a custom adapter and a custom view for the adapter item.

To preface this answer. I wasn't sure if you want to show multiple `Model` items in the `RecyclerView`, or some other data. This example assumes that you use a `List<Model>`, however, it's an easy change to make it work with another list of objects.

### Example of how the adapter could look like

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private Context _context;

    private List<Model> _items;

    public void setItems(List<Model> items)
    {
        this._items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        _context = parent.getContext();
        return new MyAdapter.ItemViewHolder(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        final MyAdapter.ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (MyAdapter.ItemViewHolder) holder;
        final Model item = _items.get(position);

        viewHolder._user.setText(item.user);
        viewHolder._exchangeName.setText(item.exchangeName);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return _items != null ? _items.size() : 0;
    }

    private static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView _user;
        private TextView _exchangeName;

        private ItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent)
        {
            super(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_view, parent, false));
            this._user = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user);
            this._exchangeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exchange_name);
        }
    }
}
```

### R.layout.adapter_view

This needs to be a view containing at least the two `TextView` views references from the `MyAdapter` above. Simple example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/content_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_view_large"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_view_small">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/placeholder"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_view_small"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exchange_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/placeholder"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_view_small"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Binding the adapter

```
//First we set up the adapter and add our List<Model> object.
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
adapter.setItems(... List<Model> items);

//Set up our RecyclerView and set the adapter.
final RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.model_list);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(_context));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first understand (and later create) the following things

1. RecyclerView Adapter
2. RecyclerView ViewHolder

After you read up on those two things the solution will be pretty clear. Just to point you in the right direction, you will have to create a custom adapter which you will use to populate your custom viewholders. Hope this helps get you going. Feel free to ask if you need any more help in this.

Comment: probably because it's a rather incomplete answer - a hint instead of a solution. Perhaps it would be better as a comment.

Comment: I guess he wants the complete code on how to do it rather than a direction on how to do it himself.

Comment: it's a coding website, people tend to want code-based answers. Also, the site is supposed to serve as a repository of knowledge for future readers. An answer effectively saying "here's a couple of keywords, go and look it up elsewhere" doesn't really provide that knowledge base, IMHO. Others may feel differently.